# Stack implementation for Undo/Redo functionality in game

Tags: java, stack, game-development

I'm working on a game, in which a player can move around a board/grid. It has moveLeft(), moveRight(), moveUp(), and moveDown() methods which move the player 1 space at a time around the board.

I'm trying to plan out my approach to required Undo/Redo functionality on the player movement (e.g. if player had gone one space to left, and Undo was called, player would move one space to right). I'm a student, and looking into Stacks.

However, when planning the logic out on paper before programming (I find this helps me when undertaking homework), I don't know if Stacks would be appropriate based on the following problem....

When each move method is called, a string 'Up', 'Down', 'Left', 'Right' is added to Stack 1, dependent on the method called. This tracks the players movement around the board.

If undo() is called, the string on top of Stack 1 is removed, and added to a new stack, 'Stack 2'. This is used to track 'undone' moves, so that redo() has a path to follow.

If redo() is called, the string on Stack 2 is removed, and back added to Stack 1.

This works perfectly, but only if you call Redo() for exactly the same amount of times as Undo() and directly after it.

E.g.:

1. Player makes 4 moves: (Stack 1 now has 4 strings)
2. Undo() is called once: (Stack 1 now has 3 strings, Stack 2 has 1 string)
3. Player makes 4 more moves: (Stack 1 now has 7 strings, Stack 2 still has 1 string)
4. Undo() is called once: (Stack 1 now has 6 strings, Stack 2 has 2 strings)
5. Redo() is called : (here is the problem) This can be called twice, because Stack 2 has 2 strings, but in reality the Player on the board should only be able to call Redo() once.

I've been trying to work on the logic behind this in isolation for the last 4 hrs! Any advice appreciated. Namely - based on the above, is it still possible to do what I need to do with Stacks, and I need to find a work around to the problem? Or should I abandon, because it is not possible.

Comment: Do you have to use a `Stack` or can you use something else (i.e. `List`)?

Comment: Looks like a good approach, but maybe you want to clear the redo stack when a move is made, because then the last operation isn't an undo anymore, which makes the redo meaningless.

Comment: @DanW I don't have to - it just seemed most logical for this scenario.

Comment: @Kenney I thought about this, but I can't see any logic that can be applied to determine when the stack should be cleared. The Undo() method calls one of the move methods because it has to take the player back a space, so I can't clear it when they are called....

Comment: @javapalava 1) Stacks inherit from Vector, which has a clear method. 2) Just clear the redo stack anytime you perform an action that is not an undo or redo.

Comment: Then you should probably rethink your design a little. It seems to me that perhaps executing an [`undo()` / `redo`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) would also push that move to the undo stack?

Comment: @javapalava Also, I don't know how knowledgable you are in programming, but if you can wrap your head around it, the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is useful in this situation.

Comment: @MageXy The only other actions that could be performed would be to call a move method - the move methods however are called when undo/redo is called (because this has to move a player on the board) so it would by default clear anytime undo/redo is called if I set it to clear when a move method is called. Not very knowledgeable(!) but will take a look at command pattern - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `Stacks` because you're unsure when to clear the undo `Stack`, you can do this with a `List`. Then, your logic can be maintained in a similar fashion:

- Keep an index of which move you are on (start at 0, increment by 1 for each new move)
- If an undo is done, decrement the index (unless you are at the beginning of the list)
- If a redo is done, increment the index (unless you are at the end of the list)
- If a new move is performed, increment the index and clear all of the moves greater than or equal to the index (thus clearing your undo/redo moves)

Then, your example is:

1. Player makes 4 moves (index is 3 and list has 4 items)
2. Undo() is called once (index is 2 and list has 4 items)
3. Player makes 4 more moves (index is 6 and list has 7 items and all undo/redo items were cleared)
4. Undo() is called once (index is 5 and list has 7 items)
5. Redo is called once (index is 6 and list has 7 items)
6. Redo is called again (rejected because no redo action available)

Comment: Thanks @Dan - the only problem, is that the Undo(), Redo() has to call the move methods in order to move the player, therefore all moves would be cleared everytime a player moved, and the index would never be able to increase past 0. There is no way to determine a 'new' move

Comment: You could pass an enum of `MoveType` into your move method. That could have `Undo`, `Redo`, and `New`. Then, your comment `move` method can act appropriately based on your `MoveType`.

Comment: OK, will look up what an enum is now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.. The whole idea of undo and redo lies around the state of your application (program). The Undo means you want to go immediately previous state of your application; similarly  it is the case with Redo. Yes the stack is best solution to keep your previous state saved. For an Undo you do a pop and push it to another stack. Use the other stack for redo operation. 
You might want to set a limit for undo and redo.
How you approach to save the state of your application is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Jor, but that doesn't help me with the above problem, of Redo() retracing the wrong steps......

Answer (score 0):

In step 3

```
Player makes 4 more moves: (Stack 1 now has 7 strings, Stack 2 still has 1 string)
```

you must empty second stack.

Comment: So, I thought about this, but..... a) I couldn't find a way to clear Stacks, and most importantly b) I can't see any logic that can be applied to determine when the stack should be cleared. The Undo() method calls one of the move methods, because it has to take the player back a space so I can't clear it when they are called....

Comment: When the player undo x3, 3 moves takes back. If he makes new moves from this point, the redo has no sense anymore. The redo moves has sense only inmediatly after an undo.

Comment: Yes, but there is no way of telling the programme when to empty the second stack - it has no way of knowing. Undo (and Redo) calls the same move methods, so if you cleared the stack everytime a move method was called, the stack would never exceed more than 1 - it would be cleared everytime undo/redo or any move method was called

Comment: Yes, true, i cant think in any solution without knowing if the last move was an undo or a new move.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to fix. Basically, a Redo is valid only if immediate previous action was an Undo.

**One solution is :** When the player makes a move then empty the Stack 2 (the Undo stack, that is used to Redo).

**Other Solution:** Defer stack 2 clearance to later. Maintain a boolean flag that tracks if previous action was an Undo (say *boolean isRecentActionUndo*), that should always represent if previous action was an Undo, by setting it to true on every call to Undo() and setting it to false on every call to Move(). Check this flag in Redo().

`if(isRecentActionUndo) {
  // perform redo
} else {
  // clear stack 2
}`

There could be other better solutions to achieve the same, to perform a valid Redo().

Comment: Not necessarily - Redo could be valid if previous action was Redo. (A player could Undo 3 moves consecutively, then Redo 3 moves consecutively which wouldn't work with a boolean :( .....Undo/Redo call the move methods to change the location of the player on the board, therefore Stack 2 would get emptied whenever a move, undo or redo method was called.